# Can you have multiple approval processes running at the same time on the same object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can you have multiple approval processes running at the same time on the same object?

Please Help.

Comment: It's not possible, you can however have multiple approvers at the same time. It would be good if you could elaborate more on your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @nicolas  As it turn out we can have multiple approval processes on same object. That is the reason why process order exist in the first place.

Comment: @Kiran I agree that you can have multiple active approval processes for the same object, but you cannot have multiple approval processes running at the same time.

Comment: @Nicolas Yes sure, that is not possible. I think I missed the running..bummer..thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Hi Mr. Nicolas . I want to try multiple approval running same time on same object , Its means all approval is related to same object . please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple active approval processes on same object but not all running. However only one approval process will get executed based on process order. If the record does not match first approval process then only it will check for the second one. You can alter the order of approval process as shown in below snapshot.

[image]

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for pointing out. As I said we can have multiple active processes but not all running.